# How to insert bunch of data in to Oracle DB?

Tags: oracle

I have a requirement to insert 12600 data in one table. The data is in doc file i need to upload all the data in particular table at one shot.

please give me a suggestion to upload the data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: may you provide some part of data from doc file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out sql*loader, which allows relatively easy and fast import into the database from text-files.

Comment: +1, simple and straightforward. An extension of this solution is to use Oracle External Tables.

Answer (score 1):

More information would be useful, but the following steps are a very general description of how to accomplish your task:

1. Open file
2. LOOP
3. Read line from file
4. If file at EOF, break out of LOOP
5. Parse line into variables
6. Insert data into table using variables from (4)
7. END LOOP
8. Close file.
9. COMMIT
10. If errors occur, ROLLBACK and exit

Share and enjoy.